# How to construct such User Interface (xml file) which run on Every screen size of Android phone in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am an android Beginer and therefore while making my initial aaps I faced problems such as- when i run my app on phones with small screen then some part of my app gets skipped 
My xml file is as folllows-
(For every person who wants to help , thanks a lot for him/her in advance)

```
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use scrollviews to display that amount of buttons.

Comment: Is it possible to put 4 buttons on a single line (horizontal) by using scrollviews @MarianoZorrilla?

Comment: you need to use HorizontalScrollView and you can put as much as you want... is not too "UI friendly", though.

Comment: Actually it's a tic tac toe game of 4x4 matrix that's why the alignment of buttons matters the most @MarianoZorrilla

Comment: You should probably look into GridLayout